# How to self-defined rank like this In Mongodb By PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-5.3, recommendation-engine, php-mongodb

the collection "question" like this

```
{
     _id:
     question:
     time:
     click_nums:
     answers: [
        {},
        {},
        ...
     ]
}
```

Now I want to rank the question like this and get the top 5:

```
 rank_condition = (now_time - time)/24*(click_nums*0.2+nums_of_answers*0.8)
```

How can I realise this , I am a newer to Mongodb..

spacial:to realise it with PHP!!!

Comment: I'd say you have to do that in your application. Maybe the new aggregation framework can do it, but probably not more efficiently. What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: 2.0.4   And I must do it like this .Because I have a big numbers of question of 50,000

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB can (currently) sort only on a field's value. It doesn't support complex expressions (as in SQL's `ORDER BY`). The new Aggregation Framework can indeed be of some help here.

You have three options:

1. Rank in the application. This is the easiest to implement.
2. Precalculate ranking position (run periodic background jobs that calculate and update ranks). This is the most efficient method to query (you might get slightly stale data).
3. Use [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) (available in 2.2 and current unstable). This is the "coolest" method. (you get to play with new toys :) )

Comment: With just 50.000 documents, I'd probably go with (1) combined with caching the result somewhere (maybe in another collection) for some period of time.